# What is Spark default username and password for a standalong installation?

Tags: oracle, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-standalone

I am trying to connect Spark to Oracle Analytics Cloud(OAC). I have a standalone spark(3.1.2) installation with Hadoop (2.7) in my windows VM. The connection requires a username, password, host and port. Can you please provide the default username and password for Spark standalone installation along with port or do i need to configure a spark cluster to have this sort of information. Thanks.

Comment: There is no default username pswd.

Comment: Hello @thebluephantom thanks for your response. Could you please tell me, how we can extract data if there is no default and password. Is there any other way we can connect to spark and extract data for analytics application. Thank you.

Comment: OAC Or spark.....

Comment: I would like to extract data from spark(i have already loaded some csv files in spark). Is there any way i can do that without spark username and password. for example, if we would like to extract data from an Oracle database, we would require the database connection details. Thank you.